# Cannot connect to my website from local network connection but can with an external network connection

Tags: internet-connection, windows-server-2008-r2, website, iis-7.5, drupal

I am hosting a website on my local network for our local Fire Explorers Program. The website is [located here](http://www.ighfdexplorers.com). I am hosting the site using Drupal 7 and IIS 7.5 running on Windows Server 2008 R2.

The problem I am having is that ever since upgrading our modem I have not been able to access the website from within my local network, which is strange because if I am not connected to my network it loads just fine. I can also access my remote desktops from both within and outside my network just fine, so it is only the website.

A prime example is on my phone when I am connected to Wi-Fi my phone uses that for data, which causes the website to not load, however as soon as I disconnect from Wi-Fi and use data from my 4G connection it loads almost instantly. Another is as soon as I get to school and use school Internet it will load right away. I am stumped as to what is wrong.

My current site binding is set like this:

[image]

Comment: Your new router does not support NAT loopback most likely, which means you cannot access the public IP that the URL resolves to from within the network that is hidden behind that IP.  Do you have DNS internally?

Comment: No I do not have internal DNS... I would like to set one up at some point in time but cannot right now due to the fact of only having 1 ip address.

Comment: An option would be to edit the `hosts` file on the internal machines and manually add the internal IP of the server against the URL

Comment: What do you mean exactly? I currently have the site bound to a local IP address on port 80. That is also port forwarded and my local IP address is a static one. Are you referring to adding the URL under the "Host name:" blank?

Comment: This is my current config for the local address: http://i.stack.imgur.com/qMdOQ.png

Comment: I have an Arris TG1682G from comcast...

Answer (score 1):

Your internal network is `10.0.0.0/24`, and this accessing the internet behind `73.242.28.179`.  You have portforwarding set up so that incoming connections to `73.242.28.179` on port `80` are forwarded to `10.0.0.25`.

And, to enable this to work with a host name, you have `www.ighfdexplorers.com` resolving to `73.242.28.179`.

The problem is that when your internal machines attempt to access `www.ighfdexplorers.com`, it resolves to `73.242.28.179` and they try to talk to the external interface of your router.

Some routers will allow this (your previous one did), and will recognise that the connection should loop back through the router to the internal server on `10.0.0.25`.  Most will not however.  This feature is called "nat loopback" or "hairpin nat" or "nat reflection".

Other than replacing the router with one that supports this feature, the alternative is to have `www.ighfdexplorers.com` resolve to  `10.0.0.25` for those on the `10.0.0.0/24` network.

The common way to do this is to have an internal DNS server that resolves `www.ighfdexplorers.com` to `10.0.0.25` and then forwards any other queries to internet based DNS servers.

If you cannot set up an internal DNS server (it could reside on 10.0.0.25 too, and does not need to be internet facing), then the less manageable way is to edit the hosts file on each internal machine (this is not easy/possible with mobile devices).

On Windows this is at `C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` and you would add an entry

```
10.0.0.25 www.ighfdexplorers.com
```

On Linux, this is at `/etc/hosts`

Comment: I Thanks, that makes sense. But how can I set up a internal DNS and host the website on the same connection

Comment: Yes but how can I set this up on an server running windows server 2008 R2?

Comment: It loads the website...

Comment: No, that is what I would like to setup. Is there a really good guide that a High-school student could easily understand that you know of?

Comment: @BrandanSchmitz What is the make/model of the router?  That would let us determine whether NAT loopback is an option.  Usually it just works it if it is there.

Comment: The make and model is Arris TG1682G, but from the information I have found, there is not a NAT loopback function available. Comcast seems to have locked down the modem firmware pretty well so there does not appear to be the option of adding that function either. However there is a Bridge mode and I have an extra HP Prolient server with dual NIC's so I might just set up something there and find a router that allows NAT loopbacks and attach that to the output of the second NIC to enable WIFI to the rest of my house...

Answer (score 0):

So I have realized that the router I have (an Arris TG1682G from Comcast) does not support NAT Loopbacks. As a temporary fix I decided to just resolve the website to my servers internal IP address by editing my Windows Hosts File. Tomorrow I am going to set my TG1682G to Bridge Mode and use an extra server I have as a router with the function of a NAT Loopback. Thanks to those who assisted me, and I hope that this will assist anyone else that may be having a similar issue.