# Configuring Port Forwarding

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ip, port-forwarding

I have a web server setup on a device which has the IP address

```
192.168.2.12
```

I can connect to this IP via the same network, however, when I try to connect to my public IP and port forward to this IP, the browser fails to load. The error - 
[image: ERROR]

## Settings

- Forward port 80 to 192.168.2.12 using TCP
- Forward port 443 to 192.168.2.12 using TCP

[image: Settings]

My public IP is

```
123.201.94.235
```

So I tried connecting to

```
123.201.94.235:80
123.201.94.235:443
```

But both failed.

Note that when I ping

```
123.201.94.235
```

the router replies.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Are you testing the connection from inside or from outside the LAN?

Comment: @grawity I have tried both. None work unless I use the internal IP (which can be used only from inside the LAN)

Comment: Then focus first on getting connections _from outside_ working; those are the simplest case. Port-forwarded connections from inside are very problematic ([see also](https://superuser.com/q/1294426), [see also](https://superuser.com/q/990076), [see also](https://superuser.com/q/1281199), [see also](https://superuser.com/q/454458))

Comment: It might be somewhat helpful to know the make and model of your router. Are there any other routers or firewall appliances in front of this router which traffic from the outside world will need to hop across to get to the server you are forwarding the traffic to? If this your Internet router or is your Internet router just a bridge with no rules or what?

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT I use a belkin router, and there are no firewalls except the one that comes with the router built-in